# How to log WCF exception shielding's {Guid} in client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using WCF Exception Shielding to map various exceptions to FaultContracts so I can limit what information I expose to the client.  I had hoped to leverage the {Guid} mapping property so I could correlate client logs and server logs:

```
<mappings>
  <add source="{Guid}" name="Id" />
  <add source="{Message}" name="MessageText" />
</mappings>
```

My service-side Exception Handling Application Block logs the exceptions, along with their GUID:

```
...
HandlingInstanceID: 262f5c59-2c89-4a00-b657-59dd4b04c406
...
```

This is working and I can see this information in the client's FaultException detail in the debugger.  However, I can't figure out how to get the Exception Handling Application Block in the client to log that detail.  I'm using the standard LoggingExceptionHandler with the TextExceptionFormatter:

```
<add name="Logging Handler"
  ...
  type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler...
  formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter... />
```

But this does not seem to include any of the custom detail.

Short of explicitly logging the exception myself (defeating part of the value of EHAB), how can I record the GUID in my client logs?

Comment: can you post your client's config sections for <loggingConfiguration> and <exceptionHandling>. As far as I am aware you will need both sections configured for this to work... that's how I'm doing it